# SQL injection, using Parameterised Queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I have some questions about how to prevent sql injectiion with the help of parameterised queries

```
sqlQuery="SELECT * FROM usersTbl WHERE username=@uname AND password=@passwd";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

SqlParameter[] par = new MySqlParameter[2];

par[0] = new SqlParameter("@uname ", SqlDbType.VarChar,25);
par[1] = new SqlParameter("@passwd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45);
```

And then I attach them to the SqlCommand and ExecuteScalar it.

For example the client insert the string `;DROP --` in the password variable, *will the parameterised query prevent the `DROP` query to be executed* ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, when the client pass `';DROP --` value in the password field, this will be parsed into

```
SELECT * 
FROM usersTbl 
WHERE username=@uname AND password=''';DROP --'
```

The `command` object will automatically escapes any single quotes found on the value.

**UPDATE 1**

As, I already told you, it won't. Because the quotes will be escaped by doubling the quotes. Example,

```
string pass_val = "'; DROP usersTbl;--";
```

when you passed that into command and its value is parameterized, this will become

```
SELECT * FROM usersTbl WHERE ... AND password='''; DROP usersTbl;--'
```

and NOT

```
SELECT * FROM usersTbl WHERE ... AND password=''; DROP usersTbl;--
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM usersTbl WHERE username=@uname AND password=''; DROP usersTbl;--   So the @passwd parameter is ''; DROP usersTbl;--.  Will it execute it? because the #passwd is VarChar(string)

Comment: Parametrized queries isn't the same as escaping query values.  When using parametrized queries, the parameters and the actual query are two distinct parts.

Comment: So it there any way to bypass it and make the DROP(or other SQL commands) to be executed?

Comment: @user1501674 hmmm are you trying to get anyway to by pass parameterized queries? unfornately, no.

Comment: So what you are telling me is that as long as I'm using parameterised queries I'm utterly protected from SQL injections ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the parameterized query will correctly escape any characters that would allow this to happen.